# Pan vs oven cooking

Tags: oven

I am 87, single, and do not want to heat up an oven to bake for a short time. Could I just put the 'baking' recipe in a top of the range pan, and accomplish the same results?

I'm not asking about cakes or cookies, but chicken dishes, roasted carrots, peppers, etc. For a single person, it seems to be a waste of electricity (and cost) to heat up an oven for 10-30 minutes of baking, for example fish, etc.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're trying to make. If you're baking a cake or cookies, no, you're not going to get the result you want. You might consider (for smaller things) getting a small counter top (toaster) oven.

Comment: Wow, it's so #EPIC that you are 87 and so tech savvy. Love it!

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19351/making-cake-without-oven, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22889/is-it-possible-to-bake-a-cake-without-an-oven, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58251/how-to-bake-cake-and-pastries-without-oven

Comment: No, not cakes or cookies, but chicken dishes, roasted carrots, peppers, etc.  For a single person, it seems to be a waste of electricity (and cost) to heat up an oven for 10-30 minutes of baking. ie fish, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, cooking in the oven and cooking on the stove will not produce the same results. The distribution of heat is completely different, the cooking times will be different, and you will have to attend to the pan while cooking to heat things evenly. You are better off starting from a stovetop recipe with the same ingredients than modifying an oven recipe for the stovetop.

There are some nice (though expensive!) toaster ovens available now where you can bake things with timed cooking. I have one friend who cooked a duck in her toaster oven and was pleased with the outcome. I am not sure how these compare in efficiency to real ovens; although the space you are heating is much smaller, the insulation is probably not as good.